# NestJS Returning an Empty Object When I try to generate JWT token

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, backend, passport.js

I am trying to use jsonwebtoken with NestJs, and have been battling with this issue whereby NestJS returns an empty object once it encouters my code line to generate a token.
Each time, I try to generate a token, the server simply responds with an empty object.

Here is my jwt strategy code for passport

```
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Inject, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { RidersService } from "../riders/riders.service";
import { DriversService } from "../drivers/drivers.service";

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly riderService: RidersService,
    private readonly driverService: DriversService,
    @Inject(ConfigService) config: ConfigService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: config.get("JWT_SECRET"),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: {
    role: string;
    iat: number;
    exp: number;
    phone: string;
  }) {
    if (!payload) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    const service = {
      rider: this.riderService,
      driver: this.driverService,
    };

    const user = await service[payload.role].findByAny(payload.phone);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const { iat, exp, ...rest } = payload;

    return rest;
  }
}
```

Now here is my AuthService stripped off

```
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Injectable, Logger, HttpException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AuthService.name);

  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}
  async register(
    phone: string,
    role: string,
  ): Promise<LoginResponseDTO | GENERIC_RESPONSE | unknown> {
    return {
      token: this.jwtService.sign({ role, phone }),
    };
  }
}
```

This line `return { token: this.jwtService.sign({ role, phone }), }` returns an empt object {} no matter what I do, once the code execution gets there, it stops and sends back an empty response.

Here is my Authmodule stripped off

```
import { JwtStrategy } from "./jwt.strategy";

import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { AuthController } from "./auth.controller";
import { PassportModule } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { JwtModule } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";


@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,

    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get<string>("JWT_SECRET"),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: configService.get<string>("JWT_EXPIRESIN") },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Here is my Authcontroller stripped off

```
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { BadRequestException, Controller, Post, Query } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ParsePhonePipe } from "./../pipes/transform-phone.pipes";

@Controller("auth")
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post("signup")
  async register(
    @Query("phone", new ParsePhonePipe()) phone: string,
    @Query("role") role: string,
  ) {
    if (!role) {
      throw new BadRequestException("user role is missing");
    }
    try {
      const response = await this.authService.register(phone, role);
      console.log(response, "RESPONSE");
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is Appmodule stripped of

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { APP_GUARD } from "@nestjs/core";

import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";

import { JwtAuthGuard } from "./auth/jwt.auth.guard";


@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>("RYDR_DB_URI"),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),

    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
    TripHistoryService,
    DriversService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The login response has nothing to do with the jwt as there are three possible response types defined.

I am unable to generate jwt token and it simply exit with an empty object {}, there is no error whatsoever.

What might I be doing wrong?

I tried to use jsonwebtoken package itself, expecting that there might be an issue with NestJs but it still failed to generate any token instead it returned an empty object as a response.

Comment: can you give more infomation like controller, LoginResponseDTO

Comment: I will update the question.

Comment: The issue has been fixed, I spent four days only to realize that my env file does not contain the  ```JWT_EXPIRESIN``` variable I was reading. I can't say why it never threw an error or warning.